# Adobe XD: Incopatibilidad de versiones 33 y 34

Tags: adobe-muse

He guardado un fichero desde la versión 34 y un compañero desde la versión 33 no puede abrirlo.

¿Hay alguna forma de que se pueda guardar de forma compatible para ambas versiones?

Comment: Por favor leer [ask] y el [help/on-topic], sobre el tipo de preguntas que se pueden realizar en el sitio. Tu pregunta parece más bien destinada al soporte técnico de Adobe. Quiero pensar que tu licencia de uso cubre ese tipo de soporte. Saludos

Comment: Hola Mauricio, por supuesto y que he hablado con soporte de Adobe y no hay solución.

Comment: Bien, si ellos no proveen una solución, no creo que alguien aparte de ellos te provea alguna. Las cosas como son. Saludos